# CSS issue- Only partial text from the span is shown in the tool tip i have created

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a css tool-tip, the html and css code and also link to fiddle is given below

[CHECK MY CODE HERE @JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/89rwu2db/)

**HTML**

```
   <a class="tooltip" href="#">CSS Tooltips 1
    <span>Tooltip1</span></a>
    </br>
     <a class="tooltip" href="#">CSS Tooltips
    <span>Tooltip This is not working for me </span></a>
```

**CSS**

```
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
}
.tooltip span {
  position: absolute;
  width:140px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #000000;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  display:none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding:2px;
}
.tooltip span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  margin-top: -8px;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  border-right: 8px solid #000000;
  border-top: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
}
.tooltip:hover span {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.8;
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

My issue is only half the text from `<span>Tooltip This is not working for me </span>` is shown in the corresponding tool-tip. I tried hard but couldn't debug it. Please help.

Thanking You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you have a fixed width. To allow the tooltip to dynamically expand to the content's width remove the `width` property and set `white-space:nowrap` to keep the text inline.

```
.tooltip span {
  position: absolute;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #000000;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  display:none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding:2px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/89rwu2db/3/

**EDIT**

As commented bellow, if you want to keep the fixed width, but wants the text to expand in height, remove the `height` property of the `span`, and it will grow (also, don't use `white-space` anymore):

```
.tooltip span {
  position: absolute;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #000000;
  width:140px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  display:none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding:2px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/89rwu2db/9/

The point is, setting a specific width or height prevents your element of growing automatically.

Comment: Thanx for the answer :) this was what i wanted bt still one thing in my mind is if i have fixed width and if i want extra text on next line  then what changes should i make ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `width` property of the second tooltip to fit all the text you want display.

Fixed Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/89rwu2db/8/

I added styling to the second span to increase the width.

```
<span style="width: 250px;">Tooltip This is not working for me </span>
```

Comment: update your work in fiddle and give me the new link thank you

Comment: got your point can you help me in getting the extra text on next line instead of changing the width.i am scratching my head on this point,what should i do for that